# How to create a jar archive using cmd?

Tags: java, jar, cmd, javac

how do I create an archive "classes.jar" which should contain 2 files ".class" (named as MyFirstClass.class and MySecondClass.class) using file I created "manifest.mf".

This must be done using the program javac, program jar and cmd.

2 files .class I already got using javac program.

This is all located in the folder C:\Task7

MyFirstClass.class file located in the folder C:\Task7\myPackage (because it is in the package "myPackage")

MySecondClass.class file located in the folder C:\Task7\myPackage\myfirstpackage (because it is in the packages myPackage and myfirstpackage)

myManifest.mf file located in the folder C:\Task7

My attempts to:

1)  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin>jar cvfm classes.jar C:\Task7 manifest -C C:\Task7 myPackage.MyFirstClass.class myPackage.myfirstpackage.MySecondClass.class

cmd answer:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Task7 (Mbp4p3m r •meCesix)
         at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
         at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146) 
         at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101) 
         at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:171)
         at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
```

2)  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin>jar cvfm classes.jar C:\Task7 manifest C:\Task7\myPackage\MyFirstClass.class C:\Task7\myPackage\myfirstpackage\MySecondClass.class

cmd answer:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Task7 (Mbp4p3m r omeCesix)
         at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
         at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
         at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
         at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:171)
         at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
```

3)  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin>jar cvfm classes.jar C:\Task7 manifest C:\Task7\myPackage MyFirstClass.class C:\Task7\myPackage\myfirstpackage MySecondClass.class

cmd answer:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Task7 (Cbpgrosm r omeCegx)
         at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
         at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
         at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
         at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:171)
         at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `jar -c` -- add the minus sign

Comment: Please don't post (links to) images of text, post the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

Keep all the file in a folder and Go to that location and use the following command-

```
jar -cvf abc.jar abc
```

if your folder name is abc.

Comment: I do not understand. What is it? I must use my manifest file and .class files (files which store in pacakges "myPackage" and "myPackage.myfirstpackage")

Answer (score 0):

If you run jar out of dir your class hierarchy is located, you shoud use -C  option before the list of files. In your case it should be: `-C C:\Task7`